# What services are included in DMZ(DeMilitarized Zone) and what services are in HSZ(High Security Zone)?

Tags: networking

In an organization, How to determine what goes into DMZ and what goes to HSZ?

Comment: Your question tends to generate mostly opinions which sadly makes it off topic here. It’s also impossible to answer without knowing your security requirements and your network topology.